# How to copy specific file from a disk

Tags: java, linux, photo

I'm looking for a script to copy specific files from a disk to one other discarding all duplicated

For examples .jpg ,.tiff,.nef

I got a pretty messy backup of all my pictures and i want to copy all pics to others disk avoiding the duplicated one

Comment: why do you want to use java ?

Comment: what do you mean by duplicated? are `lolcat.jpg` & `lolcat.tiff` duplicates? what about `lolcat.jpg` & `lolcat1.jpg`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 7, you can use the Files class.

```
File source = new File("sourcePath");
File dest = new File("destPath");
Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());
```

You can check for duplicates by collecting names (unless you have multiple files with the same name).

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
for(File f in dir) {
    if(!names.contains(f.path) {
        // copy the file using the code above
        names.add(f.path);
    }
}
```

If your logic is more complicated for determining a duplicate, replace f.path with something a little more robust. Here is one example to get your started.

To remove the extension from the path name:

```
String pathName = f.path.substring(0, f.path.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

Comment: I was fooled into thinking the OP actually wanted to write his OWN program to do this. If he did, this is how it might be done.